# Salesforce - Dashboard Refreshes

Tags: dashboard

Our sales and executive teams make use of dashboards regularly.  As provided, the teams are manually refreshing via refresh button.
automate refreshes – i.e. upon signin, loading a page, etc.?  We’re aware that SF provides the ability to schedule a batch refreshes, but that doesn’t sound very useful

Comment: ummm... what is the question?!

Comment: I need to refresh the dashboard when ever i login or refresh the page.
Is it possible ?
If it is possible please tell me the steps how to implement it as i am new to Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

[Automated refreshes](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_schedule_refresh.htm&language=nl) can be useful - for example, to update the dashboard daily, or at the beginning of the week.  They also allow you to email the dashboard, which can be good or bad depending on the dashboard.  A compact dashboard can turn out quite well in email.

That said, there are [some old posts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/salesforce-dashboard-auto-refresh) about using javascript hacks to refresh dashboards.  However, with the Analytics API, it is now possible to [refresh a dashboard via a PUT call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_dashboard_refresh.htm)

I tested in the REST explorer on workbench.developerforce.com and was able to refresh a dashboard successfully.  Note that I had to put 'abc' into the request body, as workbench requires some content in the body to place a PUT call.

That is about as far as my skills can get you, but certainly seems like you could build out utilities to refresh dashboards in a manner that is more suitable to your needs.  I do not know if doing so would violate any terms, but given that the API exists, seems like its OK to use it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enhance Salesforce Dashboard Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhance-salesforce-dashbo/mogildlgjglckdcfclpbcbidpdkjgeeb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). It would be sufficient to have it running on one machine and other users can do just a standard page refresh, unless they are using a different set of dashboard filters (each filters combination is refreshed individually).